# Is it possible to include a pre-populated indexedDB or does it need to be populated client-side?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, indexeddb, web-sql

I want to have make an offline app that will have data stored in indexedDB. I want to have that per-populated instead of requiring the javascript to add all that data on first run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to populate the IndexedDB instance client-side, there's no access to it from the server.